# Cross Domain Resource Sharing of Glyphicons

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, get, cross-domain, glyphicons

I am writing a normal asp.net MVC5 website with razor. Here, I decided to import the font icons from one our our other sites. Therefore, I called the URLs as references.

However, when I try to do this, I get an error in chrome and ie, saying that

> Font from origin 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49447' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I have run it to this problem before with a wcf application. So I tried enabling cross domain using the following code in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This didnt add the header to help with my problem.

also I tried adding the following code in to my home controller

> Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>   
>   and
>   
>   Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

The font calling is in my base layout.

I'm confused if I have done it wrong.

Is there a way I can do it with a JavaScript call which force cross domain ?